# How to store passwords in Winforms application?

Tags: winforms, security, passwords

I have some code like this in a winforms app I was writing to query a user's mail box Storage Quota.

```
DirectoryEntry mbstore = new DirectoryEntry(
      @"LDAP://" + strhome, 
      m_serviceaccount, 
      [m_pwd], 
      AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

No matter what approach I tried (like `SecureString`), I am easily able to see the password (**m_pwd**) either using Reflector or using strings tab of Process Explorer for the executable.

I know I could put this code on the server or tighten up the security using mechanisms like delegation and giving only the required privileges to the service account.

Can somebody suggest a reasonably secure way to store the password in the local application without revealing the password to hackers?

Hashing is not possible since I need to know the exact password (not just the hash for matching purpose).
Encryption/Decryption mechanisms are not working since they are machine dependent.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The sanctified method is to use CryptoAPI and the Data Protection APIs.

To encrypt, use something like this (C++):

```
DATA_BLOB blobIn, blobOut;
blobIn.pbData=(BYTE*)data;
blobIn.cbData=wcslen(data)*sizeof(WCHAR);

CryptProtectData(&blobIn, description, NULL, NULL, NULL, CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE | CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, &blobOut);
_encrypted=blobOut.pbData;
_length=blobOut.cbData;
```

Decryption is the opposite:

```
DATA_BLOB blobIn, blobOut;
blobIn.pbData=const_cast<BYTE*>(data);
blobIn.cbData=length;

CryptUnprotectData(&blobIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, &blobOut);

std::wstring _decrypted;
_decrypted.assign((LPCWSTR)blobOut.pbData,(LPCWSTR)blobOut.pbData+blobOut.cbData/sizeof(WCHAR));
```

If you don't specify CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE then the encrypted password can be securely stored in the registry or config file and only you can decrypt it. If you specify LOCAL_MACHINE, then anyone with access to the machine can get it.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned, the Data Protection API is a good way to do this.  Note that if you're using .NET 2.0 or greater, you don't need to use P/Invoke to invoke the DPAPI.  The framework wraps the calls with the `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` class.

Comment: @m_oLogin: See one of my other answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154430/persistent-storage-of-encrypted-data-using-net/154687#154687)

Answer (score 4):

I found this book by keith Brown The .NET Developer's Guide to Windows Security. It has some good samples covering all kinds of security scenarios.
Free [Online version](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook.HomePage) is also available.

Answer (score 2):

If you store it as a secure string and save the secure string to a file (possibly using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx), the only time you will have a plain text password is when you decrypt it to create your mbstore.  Unfortunately, the constructor does not take a SecureString or a Credential object.