# Best way to implement "Remember Me" check box in WinForms / WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, authentication, persistence

I want to add a "Remember Me" check box to the login form of my WPF App.  What's the best way to do this?

Currently the app logs in via a websevice call that returns an authenticated token that it uses for subsequent calls.  Should I simply two-way encrypt and store this token somewhere in the files system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435561/encrypting-credentials-in-a-wpf-application/22435672#22435672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also store it in [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) or create a User setting in your application's Settings.

**Edit:** Oren's suggestion of using DPAPI to protect information is well and good, but it doesn't store anything:

> An important point to remember is that DPAPI merely applies cryptographic protection to the data. It does not store any of the protected data; therefore applications calling DPAPI must implement their own storage of the protected data.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). See also [How to store passwords in Winforms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853/how-to-store-passwords-in-winforms-application#40867).

Answer (score 1):

I googled another solution:

Right click on your *Project -> Properties -> Setting*.

Add your variable which you need to store on client machine.

For example:

```
Name Type Scope Value

UserName String User
Password String User
```

Then, for example, you want to save preference on login button click:

```
If(CheckboxRemember.checked)
{
    YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = TextBoxUserName.Text;
    YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Password = TextPassword.Text;
    YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

On the same way, access these value on window load or application startup:

```
TextBoxUserName.Text = YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
TextPassword.Text = YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
```