# How to hide userid/password in db connection string from source?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is it possible to hide the `user id` and  `password` from source when the developer can trace the source?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you mean when they look at your file where you entered the connection string?

Comment: similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853/how-to-store-passwords-in-winforms-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425908/hide-password-on-desktop-application-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should keep the connectionstrings in web.config file and then encrypt the web.config file so that the passwords are safe.
you can find help on how to encrypt web.config file here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Just to clarify: the web.config is as _safe_ as the server itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are putting the connection string in the source code.  If you are the first thing you should do is move it to the app.config / web.config file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(VS.80).aspx

If you are already using the app.config or web.config file can you give more details.

Answer (score 2):

If using MS SQL you can use integrated auth and simply not have user name and password in the connection string:

`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

(sample copied from http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

A way to not store the password in the source is to make it a part of the server environment (read from a file, store it into an environment variable, etc.)

Comment: environment variable? How to?

Comment: By Googling "vb.net environment variable", I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the connection string, more details can be found here: [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx) and [Securing Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: but with trace the source i can see the password.